# Select checkbox with Selenium -error: Element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Please, help me to fix this, I cannot select the checkbox with python3 and selenium.

This is the error message

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>   Element could not be scrolled into view

Link to geckodriver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

--Code from here ---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os


url = "https://partner.ingatlan.com/zalabanyi.rezso"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/Test/Desktop/geckodriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-contact-email')
python_button.click()

search_input_box = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_name")
search_input_box.send_keys("John Doe")

find_phone = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_phoneNumber")
find_phone.send_keys("00447455555")

find_email = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_email")
find_email.send_keys("noreply@email.com")

find_message = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_message")
find_message.send_keys("This is my message for you")

find_agree = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_acceptPrivacyPolicy")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

find_agree.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select checkbox using JavaScript:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("contact_message_acceptPrivacyPolicy"))
```

Another way is to use `Actions` to click on label:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains
...

checkbox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='contact_message_acceptPrivacyPolicy']")
action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(checkbox, 1, 1).click().perform()
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating why this works and the previous approach doesn't?